# Magento DevBox Beta Speeds Magento 2 Setup - Container is not working

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, varnish, docker

I have installed the docker on Windows 7. It's working fine and run as well.

I installed the Magento site using Varnish and Redis, so works fine.

When I tried to enable the **deploy:mode:set** to developer mode my container stopped.

Comment: It's  probably better to report this on github https://github.com/magento/magento2devbox-web/issues instead of here for a quicker resolution.

Comment: Docker is not supporting window 7. I had also tried in windows 7,8 and Window 10 and it didn't work for me. I think the problem you are having seems to be compatibility issues.